# How do I get ALL Users through REST API?

Tags: rest-api

Forgive the newbie question, but I have not been able to find the answer to it in the docs. I'm trying to get all users through REST.

The Users I'm referring to are the users in my company. Not Users in a specified account.

In "**Classic View**", when you click on "**Manage Users**" > "**Users**".

[image]

How do I get these users through REST?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just use a query, the same as you'd query most other types of data:

```
/services/data/v41.0/query?q=SELECT+UserName+FROM+User
```

You can add filters to get just active users, or users with a certain license, etc, as well. You'll want to look at the [SOQL reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_sosl_intro.htm) and the [REST Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm) documentation.

Comment: May want to also do some checks after to determine from your result that there are more records/ no more records